# Java Object - Graph as Hash of List

Tags: java, list, graph, hash

I have a college assingment and i'm stuck at one part

I have to make a Graph representation with Matrix and Hash of list. First one is no problem. The second is breaking me down.

I need to print the order of the graph on order from the minor origin to the bigger, where destination and weight is printed, as shown below:

origin, destination, weight

- 0,1,1
- 0,2,1
- 1,3,2
- 1,4,2
- 2,3,2
- 3,4,1

For example, if 0,1,1 is printed, then 1,0,1 can not be printed.

But my method show all of them, include the repetition. I tried to check if the element has already been printed, but i can not call the HASH function that check that from LIST class.

In my perception the hierarchy is GRAPH->HASH->LIST in terms of callin.

So basically i have hash of list where the hash index is the origin and the elements of the list are destination where there is edges.

The code for CELL elements of the list are described below:

```
    class Celula {
    public int elemento; 
    public int peso;
    public Celula prox; 
    public Celula ant; 

    Celula(int elemento, int peso) {
        this.elemento = elemento;
        this.peso = peso;
        this.prox = null;
        this.ant = null;
    }

    Celula(int elemento, int peso, Celula prox) {
        this.elemento = elemento;
        this.peso = peso;
        this.prox = prox;
        this.ant = null;
    }
 }
```

The code for LIST is here:

```
public class Lista {
private Celula primeiro; 
private Celula ultimo; 

public Lista() {
    primeiro = new Celula(-1, -1);
    ultimo = primeiro;
}

public void mostrar(int a) {
    for (Celula i = primeiro.prox; i != null; i = i.prox) {
        if (i.elemento < a) {
            if(this.tabela[a].pesquisar(i) == false){
                System.out.println(a+","+i.elemento +","+i.peso);       
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

The code for HASH is here:

```
class HashIndiretoLista {
Lista tabela[];
int tamanho;
final int NULO = -1;

public HashIndiretoLista (){
    this(7);
}

public void mostrar(int size){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        tabela[i].mostrar(i);
    }
}
```

The code for the GRAPH is here:

```
class Grafo{
int completo, tipo, tamanho;

public Grafo(){
    this.completo = 0;
    this.tipo = -1;
    this.tamanho = 0;
}

public Grafo(int tipo){
    this.tipo = tipo;
    this.completo = 0;
    this.tamanho = 0;
}

public static void build_graph(){
    String line;
    int ori, dest, weight, tipo, t_arestas, vertice;
    Arq.openRead("./pub.in");
    tipo = Integer.parseInt(Arq.readLine());
    t_arestas = Integer.parseInt(Arq.readLine());
    Grafo graph_info = new Grafo(tipo);
    graph.mostrar(t_arestas);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    build_graph();
 }
}
```

The input file is this:
0
5
0,1,1
0,3,6
0,4,2
3,4,3
FIM
3
2,4

The function in the **LIST** that print the HASH list is ***public void mostrar(int a)***

Comment: I copied the code to Eclipse and it showed me errors: Class Lista uses "this.tabela[a]" in mostrar(int a) and doesn't have such a field. Class Grafo uses unknown class Arq.

Comment: Sorry about that. I use an adapter to read from archives. Updated with the Arq code.

Comment: Can you please reduce this to a [mcve]? Mostly, to help others help you, but also often when you get stuck, removing all the code that is irrelevant to _just_ the problem you're having will make you see why it's not working the way you thought. Hard code anything that isn't relevant in your mcve, so don't parse user input, just immediately build the graph from your example, etc; it's an essential step during the debugging process that is most important when you're so stuck you need to turn to external code reviewers for help.

Comment: OK i will do that. i was afraid that limiting the scope would make the problem not verifiable. But i will try to do it and update the post. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. Changed the method to :

```
public void mostrar(int a) {
    for (Celula i = primeiro.prox; i != null; i = i.prox) {
        if (i.elemento > a) {
            if(this.pesquisar(a) == false){
                System.out.println(a+","+i.elemento +","+i.peso);       
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This allowed me to use the function pesquisar of the Hash table that called the method mostrar. So basically was a hierarchy problem, i wasn't able to call the method to verify without the this. I was thinking that since i was on the LIST class this would call the LIST class and it methods. Thanks for everyone that show interest on helping.